# Резиновая вёрстка: пустое простанство справа

Tags: html, css, адаптивная-верстка

Делая резиновую вёрстку, установил минимальную ширину `body` и сделал так, чтобы хэдер и футер растягивались по ширине окна, а всё содержимое между мини - центрировалось:

```
body{
    ...
    min-width: 1024px;
    ...
}   

header, footer{
    ...
    width: 100%;
    ...
}   

main{
    ...
    width: 1024px;
    margin: 0 auto;  
    ...
}
```

Во-первых, такое решение не привело к тому, что при 1024px горизонтальная полоса прокрутки отсутствует: они исчезает только где-то при 1260px.

Eсли при начальном размере экрана менее 1260px прокрутить влево, то справа окажется пустое пространство, как показано на рисунке ниже:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопросы у меня такие:

1. Как убрать скроллбар при ширинах окна до 1024px?
2. Как убрать пустое пространство при любых ширинах окна?

Comment: 1. Убрать скроллбар до 1024px можно убрав у `body` `min-width: 1024px`. Скроллбар появляется, потому что задана минимальная ширина. 2. Без вашего кода трудно понять в чем может быть проблема. [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Если убрать минимальную ширину у body - тогда хедер и футер перестанут растягиваться по ширине экрана когда она более 1024px, и таким образом это будет уже не резиновая вёрстка.

Comment: хедер и футер будут растягиваться при ширине более 1024px, если не задавать `body` `min-width: 1024px` https://jsfiddle.net/jg6cu877/. Скроллбар до 1024px еще появляется из-за `main` `width: 1024px;`.

Comment: Благодарю Вас за решение. К сожалению, когда я стал адаптировать его под свою ситуацию, образовалась ещё одна проблема. Я рассмотрел её [в отдельном вопросе](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/542294/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE).

Comment: stackanon, можно ещё узнать, почему именно скроллбар появляется из-за main width: 1024px;? Ведь раз main width: 1024px; и располагается точно посередине родительского блока, то по идее никакого скроллбара не должно быть при ширинах менее 1024px.

Comment: Потому что не задано никакого поведения элементам до ширины 1024px, браузер пытается отображать, что ему задано и поэтому рендерит элемент шириной 1024px, который не помещается в окно меньше 1024px и для просмотра элемента появляется скроллбар. Можно задать `overflow:hidden;` для родительского элемента, например, здесь это для `body` и скроллбар появляется не будет, но  с этим свойством будет обрезаться контент, что нежелательно.

Comment: Я, должно быть не очень понимаю, какие стилевые настройки Вы подразумеваете под поведением элементов. Тип элемента (блочный, строчный и т. д.)? Margin? Позиционирование?

Comment: Стилевые настройки ширины `width`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42186/discussion-between-gurebu-bokofu-and-stackanon).