# Резиновая верстка: проблема с центрированием содержимого

Tags: html, css, адаптивная-верстка

В этом вопросе рассматривается проблема, которая была обнаружена в одном из предложенных решений в ответе на другой мой вопрос: [Резиновая вёрстка: пустое простанство справа](https://jsfiddle.net/jg6cu877/).

Задача довольно посредственная: сделать резиновую вёрстку с шириной целевого содержимого, допустим, 1024px. Оно должно центрироваться при расширении окна.

В предыдущем вопросе был предложен [код](https://jsfiddle.net/jg6cu877/), позволяющий растягивать `header`, `main` и `footer` по ширине экрана. Я добавил в этот код блоки-центровщики, в которых, собственно, и будет располагаться целевое содержимое ([ссылка на код](https://jsfiddle.net/9w26zm5e/)). Вот так примерно это будет выглядеть (я нарисовал центровщики полупрозрачными):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И всё бы замечательно, но есть один деффект. Если сузить окно до размера менее 1024px, а затем прокрутить скроллбар, то окажется, что правая граница header, main и footer окажутся под центровщиками. Вы можете наблюдать этот эффект в приведённом мною [коде](https://jsfiddle.net/9w26zm5e/).

Вопрос очевидный: как убрать этот деффект?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтоб не было дефектов (скроллбаров) до ширины равной 1024px, нужно в адаптивной или резиновой верстке задавать поведение элементов до 1024px. Посмотреть разницу между адаптивностью и резиной можете [здесь](https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-responsive-and-adaptive-design/). Далее поищите информацию, как верстать под выбранный метод.

Небольшой пример https://jsfiddle.net/9w26zm5e/1/

```css
body {
  background: orange;
}
header,
footer {
  background: lightblue;
  width: 100%;
}
.centering {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
main {
  background: lightgreen;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .centering {
    width: 100px;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="centering">
      Header
    </div>
  </header>
  <main>
    <div class="centering">
      Main
    </div>
  </main>
  <footer>
    <div class="centering">
      Main
    </div>
  </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: Обратите внимание на то, что при длинах, чуть-чуть превышающих 300px в вашем решении, центровщики оказываются длиннее header, footer и т. д. Хотя в окне мини-браузера JSFiddle вертикального скроллбара нет, разрабатывая реальный сайт я обнаружил, что если отключить вертикальный скроллбар, то этого эффекта не будет (но тогда нельзя будет и прокручивать). Почему тогда этот эффект имеет место и в Вашем примере?

Comment: Центровщики оказываются длиннее из-за дефолтных стилей `body`, `margin` которого не равен 0,  `margin` от `body` прибавляется к ширине всего содержимого и поэтому оно становится немного шире. Решить это можно обнулением `margin` у `body` [пример](https://jsfiddle.net/9w26zm5e/3/) или заданием меньшей ширины у центровщика, по сравнению с `@media screen and (max-width: 300px)` [пример](https://jsfiddle.net/9w26zm5e/4/)

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ. Для того, чтобы полностью исчерпать данную тему, осталось только узнать, как избежать того же эффекта при наличии вертикального скроллбара.

Comment: Не понял, что не так с вертикальным скроллбаром, он появляется, когда высота содержимого страницы больше высоты размера экрана. Может быть стоит поискать информацию, как вертикальный скроллбар влияет на страницу.

Answer (score 1):

В принцие, [такое](https://jsfiddle.net/7j9zf29t/) решение *почти* идеальное. Я задал до определённой ширины (назовём её контрольной шириной) браузера абсолютную ширину `body` (в реальности это может быть, например, ширина экрана iPhone 320px), а дальше всё прекрасно растягивается до бесконечности. Eсли Вы сузите окно менее величины контрольной ширины, то при скроллинге ничего аномального тоже не будет.

Единственный недостаток - тот, о котором я говорил в комментарии: при небольном превышении контрольной ширины `header`, `main` и `footer` оказываются меньше своих центровщиков, но при дальнейшем расширении это быстро проходит. Вот если этот эффект убрать, тогда задачу можно считать полностью решенной.

```
<body>
  <header>
     <div class="centering">
         Header
     </div>
  </header>
  <main>
    <div class="centering">
         Main
    </div>
  </main>
  <footer>
    <div class="centering">
         Main
    </div>
  </footer>
</body>

body {
  background: orange;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  body{
    width:300px;
    background: blue;
  }
}
header,
footer {
  background: lightblue;
  width: 100%;
}

.centering{
  background: rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

main {
  background: lightgreen;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```